# How is the game affected by the species you choose?

Tags: ramble-planet

At the beginning of the game, you are nothing but an amorphous cloud of nanobots.  You must interface with a crewmember and take over their body to venture out into the world.  There are 9 crewmembers to choose from, from 3 different species.

Combat appears to be the same across the races; the Dropbulge doesn't have any advantage over the Palsink that I can see, they both start at level 0.

However, I did come across another Palsink who said he was 'glad to see another member of the species', and gave me something (I forget what, exactly).  Are there some items you can only get as a certain species?  Is it possible to get all ship parts as any species?

[image: Dropbulge are aggressive pirates and warlords.]

[image: Palsink are cunning traders and explorers.]

[image: Holdbox are eccentric scholars and mystics.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of species only matters for [one puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173450/3114) and has no effect on combat. However, it does change the flavor of the game. The text from the BOOKLET item reflects your species' attitudes. Also, the ending screens change as well. However, only if your score is good enough or you've found certain items (i.e. the NUKE).

Comment: Good to know.  I never thought about that booklet text, that's a neat touch.  Which puzzle does it impact?  I think I know the answer already, but can you add that information for posterity?